# C# Reflection: Getting the fields of a DataRow from a Typed DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, strongly-typed-dataset, datarow

I am currently building a method that takes an object that is of type `DataRow` from a typed DataSet, and then returning a string in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) format of the fields in the DataRow (for use in a Web Service).

By using `System.Reflection`, I am doing something like this :

```
public string getJson(DataRow r)
    {
        Type controlType = r.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] props = controlType.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo controlProperty in props)
        {

        }
        return "";
    }
```

And then in the `foreach` statement, I would iterate every field and get the field name and value, and format it into JSON.

---

The problem is that when iterating over the `props` (of type `PropertyInfo[]`), I am getting properties that I do not want to be iterated over:

[alt text http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/2001/datarowreflectionht0.gif](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/2001/datarowreflectionht0.gif)

As you can see from the above image, I only need the fields that range from `0 - 11` in the `props` array, because those are the 'real fields' of this particular typed row.

So my question is, **How can I get the fields of the Typed DataRow only, and not the other 'metadata' ?**

---

**[UPDATE with Solution]**

As [Mehrdad Afshari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431050/c-reflection-getting-the-fields-of-a-datarow-from-a-typed-dataset#431058) suggested, instead of using `Reflection`, I am using the `Table.Columns` array.

Here is the completed function:

```
public string GetJson(DataRow r)
{
    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataColumn item in r.Table.Columns)
    {
        json.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\" : \"{1}\"", item.ColumnName, r[item.ColumnName].ToString()));
        if (index < r.Table.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            json.Append(", ");
        }
        index++;
    }
    return "{" + json.ToString() + "}";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you use `row.Table.Columns` property instead of reflection?