# How can I limit DataSet.WriteXML output to typed columns?

Tags: ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm trying to store a lightly filtered copy of a database for offline reference, using ADO.NET DataSets. There are some columns I need *not* to take with me. So far, it looks like my options are:

- Put up with the columns
- Get unmaintainably clever about the way I `SELECT` rows for the DataSet
- Hack at the XML output to delete the columns

I've deleted the columns' entries in the DataSet designer. `WriteXMl` still outputs them, to my dismay. **If there's a way to limit `WriteXml`'s output to typed rows, I'd love to hear it.**

I tried to filter the columns out with careful `SELECT` statements, but ended up with a `ConstraintException` I couldn't solve. Replacing one table's query with `SELECT *` did the trick. I suspect I could solve the exception given enough time. I also suspect it could come back again as we evolve the schema. I'd prefer not to hand such a maintenance problem to my successors.

All told, I think it'll be easiest to filter the XML output. I need to compress it, store it, and (later) load, decompress, and read it back into a DataSet later. Filtering the XML is only one more step — and, better yet, will only need to happen once a week or so.

Can I change `DataSet`'s behaviour? Should I filter the XML? Is there some fiendishly simple way I can query pretty much, but not quite, everything without running into `ConstraintException`? Or is my approach entirely wrong? I'd much appreciate your suggestions.

**UPDATE:** It turns out I copped `ConstraintException` for a simple reason: I'd forgotten to delete a strongly typed column from one DataTable. It wasn't allowed to be `NULL`. When I selected all the columns *except* that column, the value was `NULL`, and… and, yes, that's profoundly embarrassing, thank you so much for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as easy as **`Table.Columns.Remove("UnwantedColumnName")`.** I got the lead from 
[Mehrdad's wonderfully terse answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431050/c-reflection-getting-the-fields-of-a-datarow-from-a-typed-dataset#431058). I was delighted when `Table.Columns` turned out to be malleable.